# A better way to print nested arrays

Tags: python, arrays, python-2.7

Let's say I have this nested array:

```
foo = [['bar', 'bar'], ['bar', 'bar']]
```

I've usually printed it out like this, using nested `for` loops:

```
for array in foo:
    for bar in array:
        print bar
```

Since I felt this question was too insufficient for Codereview, I'm asking here, is there any better way to do this than my current method?

Comment: Why can't you print directly?

Comment: @simonzack Like this? `print foo`. I don't do that because it would print out `[['bar', 'bar'], ['bar', 'bar']]`.

Comment: So you want to print each inner-most element, one at a time?

Comment: @dano Yes, that is what I would like.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this to print out the elements by themselves:

```
print('\n'.join(itertools.chain(*foo)))
```

Comment: I think OP would rather have `'\n'.join(...)`, but good answer!

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the `pprint` module. You can do something like this:

```
from pprint import pprint

pprint(foo, width=3) // width = 80 but your sequence is shorter than a line
```